# LNK2001, again

Tags: c, lnk2001

I looked for similar problems, but the only topic might be the one on the use of a library, which I would avoid... here is my issue, I get this error:

```
1>Signal generator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl findMaxModulus(double *,int)" (?findMaxModulus@@YANPANH@Z)
```

I am using visual studio professional 2008 to develop a c program. I have a main file and another file with all the functions I wrote, myFunctions.h/c. The problem is that these errors do not come out when I include "myFunctions.c", while they come out when I include "myFunctions.h".

i am doing what i remember from university (i am much more into matlab now), which is

```
/* Home-made includes */
#include "myType.h"
#include "myFunctions.h"
```

just after the inclusion of the othe headers (stdlib, math, etc...)

any guess? thank you

Comment: The problem was I did not add the files to the resources folder in the project explorer, which I guess is what ThiefMaster said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means the linker could not find the function. This most likely means that you aren't compiling your `myFunctions.c` file at all. Make sure it's added as a "source file" to the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: ok, this is something I thought about, but the point is: when I include the header in the main file, isn't the associated .c file compiled automatically?

Comment: That's completely unrelated. They don't even need the same or similar names.

Comment: @user1875202 - you need to specifically add all the `.c` files to the project to make the compiler compile them.

Comment: So, if I write at the beginning:
    #include "myFunctions.h"
    #include "myFunctions.c"
is a proper solution or is it a wrong way to code?

Comment: @user1875202 It's a bad way to add code, because you can't do it from more than one file (then you'd get "duplicate definition" errors). Follow the normal system of definitions in headers, code in source files, and link in the objects you need when making the executable or library at the end.

Comment: ok, but I am not dealing with objects, since I am dealing with c... do i really have to build a library? I haven't been programming in c for a long time, but i remember that i have never done something like that...

Comment: I think I got it, I had to add the files to the resource folder... now i have a completely different problem "precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)", i will try to cope with it, thanks!

Comment: I wish this was on the first page when you Google "LNK2001", instead of that other heap of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try on `gcc` try to compile both `.c` files same like this below:

`gcc -Wall main.c myfunction.c -o final.out`

You are missing the other `.c` file.So in the linking phase linker could not resolve the external symbol (which is your function). Try as I said.

For Visual Studio: You need to check whether all the source files are checked to make a build. there is an option to include number of files from the several source files.

Comment: i am using visual studio and i would like to sort the problem in that environment. I managed to make the software work, but i do not understand why it is ok when i include myFunctions.c and not ok when i include myFunctions.h